# Can I mix variable interpolation with StringResourceModels in Wicket?

Tags: text, properties, wicket, string-interpolation

I want to add a label that Displays a message like this:
`privateFieldOfModel (interpolatedVariable: privateFieldOfModel)`.
E.g.: John Doe (Has id: 63412313), John Doe (Hat Id: 63412313)

My property file looks like this:

```
languageDependentCode=CodeInSelectedLanguage //property is different for every lang
labelInfo=${name} (${languageDependentCode}: ${id})
```

My Java:

```
div.add(new Label("infoLabel", new StringResourceModel("labelInfo",
        new Model<>(myModel))));
```

And my Model looks somehow like this:

```
public class MyModel{
    private String id, name;
    //getters for both
}
```

Running it will however throw this exception:

```
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: 
No get method defined for class: class MyModel expression: languageDependentCode
```

Which I can somehow understand. Is there a way I could insert `languageDependentCode` into this property without wicket thinking it must come from `MyModel`?
Note:
`MessageFormat.format()` would not serve my purpose, since it wouldn't replace `${languageDependentCode}` on language change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use NestedStringResourceLoader (available since 7.4.0/8.0.0-M1, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-6193).

See the commit with the tests/examples: https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=wicket.git;h=2b12b89

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stuck with `Wicket 7.3`

Comment: Wicket is open source. You can copy just this class into your application and use it.

Comment: Yet one question rises: Why do I have to call `loaders.clear();`? Wouldn't it remove all other loaders I have?

Comment: They will be nested. The single loader will delegate to them.